# Trying to code a troubleshooting system for an assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner at Python and the problem I'm having is something new to me. I'm not exactly sure.

```
import sys
import time
import string

def programExit():
    print("Thanks for using!")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    pressEnter = input("Press <ENTER> to exit the program.")

print("REMINDER: Please do not include special characters (i.e. @, £, >) in your problem.")
time.sleep(2)
userInput = input("What is the problem?: ")

removePunc = set(string.punctuation)
userInput = ''.join(ch for ch in userInput if ch not in removePunc)
userInput = userInput.lower()
userInput = userInput.split()

def solutionBattery():
    print("From what I can tell, there is a problem with your battery. There" \
          " seems to be multiple fixes for you issue. The first fix is: " \
          "'Place your phone on charge.' The second fix is: 'Get our battery " \
          "replaced or repaired by a technician.")

batteryList = ['battery', 'low', 'charge', 'depleted', 'percentage']
screenList = ['screen', 'display', 'cracked', 'broken', 'scratched']
softwareList = ['slow', 'unresponsive', 'respond', 'wifi', 'data', 'crashing']
storageList = ['storage', 'space', 'full', 'room', 'volume']

if batteryList in userInput == True:
    print("Getting solution...")
    time.sleep(1.25)
    print(solutionBattery())
    time.sleep(7)
    programExit()
```

It doesn't seem to want to print the test solution I have, and I'm not exactly sure why it isn't doing that. I've tried looking on here for an answer in other treads but I can't exactly find anything that is relevant to my problem. Hopefully you guys could help me out?? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `if` statement. Both conditions you have evaluate to `False`

```
batteryList in userInput #False
userInput == True #False
```

So your `if` block is not running.

#### `userInput == True`

This is not needed as what ever is in `userInput` is not *equal* to `True`, but *evaluates* to `True`.

#### `batteryList in userInput`

First, this is the wrong way around. It should be `userInput in batteryList`. However this will still fail because earlier you split up the user's input:

```
userInput = userInput.split()
```

And this returns a list. So currently `userInput` = `["battery"]`, and this is not in the `batteryList`. However: `"battery"` is, so we just need to get the first item from the user's input:

```
if userInput[0] in batteryList:
    #do stuff
```